# How to get the desired formatted hash from a string in an efficient way with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I want to hash in a particular format when a string appears in the below format:

**Given string:**

```
str = 'A
A = B
A = B = C
A = B = D
A = E = F
G = H
G = I
G = J'
```

**# Into a hash like this (required hash pattern):**

```
{
  "A" => {
    "B" => {
      "C" => nil,
      "D" => nil
    },
    "E" => {
      "F" => nil
    },
  },
  "G" => {
     "H" => nil,
     "I" => nil,
     "J" => nil
  }
}
```

**I tried many ways, but this is the closest:**

```
output = Hash.new
line_hash = Hash.new
str.each_line do |line|
  arr = line.split("=")
  e = arr.first.strip
  line_hash[e] = {}
  arr.each_with_index do |ele, i|
    break unless arr[i+1]
    line_hash[ele.strip] = arr[i+1] unless output.keys.include?(ele.strip)
  end
  output[e] = line_hash unless output.keys.include?(e)
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
str = "A\nA = B\nA = B = C\nA = B = D\nA = E = F\nG = H\nG = I\nG = J"

curr = h = {}

str.each_line { |l| 
  l.chomp.split(/\s*=\s*/m).each { |c| 
    curr = curr[c] ||= {}; 
  }
  curr = h 
}

puts h
# => {
#  "A" => {
#    "B" => {
#      "C" => {},
#      "D" => {}
#    },
#    "E" => {
#      "F" => {}
#    }
#  },
#  "G" => {
#    "H" => {},
#    "I" => {},
#    "J" => {}
#  }
# }
```

I hope you’ll excuse me for leaving empty hashes instead of null values at leaves for sake of solution clarity.

To nullify leaves:

```
def leaves_nil! hash
   hash.each { |k,v| v.empty? ? hash[k] = nil : leaves_nil!(hash[k]) }  
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will try to get null instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get that output by something like this

```
str = 'A
A = B
A = B = C
A = B = D
A = E = F
G = H
G = I
G = J'

curr = h = {}
lines = str.split("\n").map{|t| t.split(/\s*=\s*/m) }
lines.each do |line| 
  line.each { |c| curr = curr[c.strip] = curr[c.strip] ||  ((line.last == c) ? nil : {});  }
  curr = h
end
```

**output**

```
#=>  {
#        "A" => {
#            "B" => {
#                "C" => nil,
#                "D" => nil
#            }, "E" => {
#                "F" => nil
#            }
#        }, "G" => {
#            "H" => nil,
#            "I" => nil,
#            "J" => nil
#        }
#    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `= curr[c.strip] = curr[c.strip]`?

Answer (score 1):

This is another way that requires less data to build the hash. If, for example, the line

```
A = B = C = D
```

is present, there is no need for either of the following:

```
A = B
A = B = C
```

and the order of the lines is unimportant.

**Code**

```
def hashify(str)
  str.lines.each_with_object({}) { |line, h|
    line.split(/\s*=\s*/).reduce(h) { |g,w|
      (w[-1] == "\n") ? g[w.chomp] = nil : g[w] ||= {} } }
end
```

**Example**

```
str =<<_
A = B = C
G = I
A = B = D
A = E = F
G = H
A = K
G = J
_

hashify(str)
  #=> {"A"=>{"B"=>{"C"=>nil, "D"=>nil}, "E"=>{"F"=>nil}, "K"=>nil},
  #    "G"=>{"I"=>nil, "H"=>nil, "J"=>nil}}
```

**Explanation**

For `str` above:

```
a = str.lines
  #=> ["A = B = C\n", "A = B = D\n", "A = E = F\n",
  #    "G = H\n", "G = I\n", "G = J\n"]
```

Notice that [String#lines](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-lines), unlike `split(/'\n'/)`, keeps the newline characters. Keeping them at this point was intentional; they serve an important purpose, as will be shown below.

```
enum = a.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["A = B = C\n", "A = B = D\n", "A = E = F\n", "G = H\n",
  #                  "G = I\n", "G = J\n"]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert the enumerator to an array to see the elements the [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each) will pass to the block:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["A = B = C\n", {}], ["A = B = D\n", {}], ["A = E = F\n", {}],
  #    ["G = H\n", {}], ["G = I\n", {}], ["G = J\n", {}]]
```

`enum` now invokes `each` to pass each element into the block:

```
enum.each { |line, h| line.split(/\s*=\s*/).reduce(h) { |g,w|
            (w[-1] == '\n') ? g[w.chomp] = nil : g[w] ||= {} } }
  #=> {"A"=>{"B"=>{"C\n"=>{}, "D\n"=>{}}, "E"=>{"F\n"=>{}}},
  #    "G"=>{"H\n"=>{}, "I\n"=>{}, "J\n"=>{}}}
```

The first value that `Array#each` passes into the block is:

```
["A = B = C\n", {}]
```

which is decomposed or "disambiguated" into it's two elements and assigned to the block variables:

```
line = "A = B = C\n"
h = {}
```

We now execute the code in the block:

```
b = line.split(/\s*=\s*/)
  #=> ["A", "B", "C\n"]
b.reduce(h) { |g,w|
  (w[-1] == '\n') ? g[w.chomp] = nil : g[w] ||= {} }
  #=> {}
```

The initial value for `reduce` is the hash `h` that we are building, which is initially empty. When `h` and`"A"` are passed into the block,

```
g = h #=> {}
w = "A"
```

so (noting that double quotes are needed for `"\n"`)

```
w[-1] == "\n"
  #=> "A" == '\n'
  #=> false
```

so we execute

```
g[w] ||= {}
  #=> g['A'] ||= {} 
  #=> g['A'] = g['A'] || {}
  #=> g['A'] = nil || {}
  #=> {}
```

so now

```
h #=> {"A"=>{}}
```

`g[w] => {}` is then passed back back to `reduce` and the block variables for the second element passed to the block are:

```
g = g["A"] #=> {}
w = "B"
```

Since

```
w[-1] == "\n" #=> false
```

we again execute

```
g[w] ||= {}
 #=> g["B"] ||=> {} => {}
```

and now

```
h #=> {"A"=>{"B"=>{}}}
```

Lastly, `[g["B"], "C\n"]` is passed into the block, decomposed and assigned to the block variables:

```
g = g["B"] #=> {}
w = "C\n"
```

but the presence of the newline character in `w` results in

```
w[-1] == "\n" #=> true
```

telling us it is the last word in the line, so we need to strip off the newline character and set the value to `nil`:

```
g[w.chomp] = nil
  #=> g["C"] = nil
```

resulting in:

```
h #=> {"A"=>{"B"=>{"C"=>nil}}}
```

Leaving the newline character in the string provided the needed "flag" for processing the last word on each line differently than the others.

The other lines are processed similarly.